# Moving from preg_replace to preg_replace_callback

Tags: php

I've had a good look through all the previous topics and I don't understand enough PHP to use them to answer my questions so sorry in advance if this is really simple!

```
{
    $content = preg_replace('/\$([\w]+)/e', '$0', $this->getTemplateStyle());
    $custom_css = $this->getCustomCSS();
    return $content.$custom_css;
}
```

And I need to replace `preg_replace` with `preg_replace_callback`. I know it's not a simple switch and that I need to add more to the code, but I don't know what to add.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score -1):

[SOLVED]
You seem to be trying to inject variables from the current scope into your string. I'll leave aside why this is a bad idea and assume there is no user input involved. First get the current scope:

```
$scope = get_defined_vars();
```

Next use the callback:

```
preg_replace_callback('/\$(\w+)/',function($m) use ($scope) {if( isset($scope[$m[1]])) return $scope[$m[1]]; else return $m[0];}, $this->getTemplateStyle());
```

Job done. – @Niet the Dark Absol

Comment: If it's a duplicate, why are you answering?

Comment: I'm really grateful for the link to the other answer, but my php knowledge is too basic to translate how I can use it for my problem.  I haven't got the same bit '/&#(\d+);/m' and I guess I'm trying to get it to call a style sheet, but I don't know what to change.  I really need some code I can cut and paste - sorry to be so dumb!

Comment: You seem to be trying to inject variables from the current scope into your string. I'll leave aside why this is a bad idea and assume there is no user input involved. First get the current scope: `$scope = get_defined_vars();`. Next use the callback: `preg_replace_callback('/\$(\w+)/',function($m) use ($scope) {if( isset($scope[$m[1]])) return $scope[$m[1]]; else return $m[0];}, $this->getTemplateStyle());`. Job done.